# Multiple choice, answer key

Tags: exam

The solution,the answers keys are show in vertical,in this way it need big space and when i print them, i will use more paper and I want to get that answer key can show in horizontal.   Thank you

```
\documentclass{exam} \usepackage{answers}

\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}

\newtheorem{ex}{}{} \renewcommand\questionlabel{} 
\renewcommand\questionshook{\leftmargin0pt} \begin{document}

\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1] \section{Problems}

\begin{ex} 
\begin{questions} 
\question One of these things is not like the 
others; one of these things is not the same. Which one is different?

\begin{oneparchoices} 
\choice John 
\choice Paul 
\choice George 
\choice Ringo 
\choice Socrates \end{oneparchoices}
\begin{sol} 
Socrates 
\end{sol} 
\end{questions} \end{ex}

\begin{ex} \begin{questions} \stepcounter{question} \question One of these 
numbers is perfect.

\begin{oneparchoices} 
\choice $2$ 
\choice $28$ 
\choice $5$ 
\choice $3$ 
\choice $7$ \end{oneparchoices} \end{questions} 
\begin{sol} 
$7$ 
\end{sol} 
\end{ex}

\Closesolutionfile{ans} 
\section{Solutions} 
\input{ans1}

\end{document}
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: This question is pretty unclear. Please add a code example and rephrase your question according to your needs.

Comment: I did some change,maybe now it will be more clear@TeXnician

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine how solutions are displayed.  You can change how much space to put between answers or other aspects of the formatting as you see fit.

```
\documentclass{exam} \usepackage{answers}

\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}

\newtheorem{ex}{}{} \renewcommand\questionlabel{} 
\renewcommand\questionshook{\leftmargin0pt} \begin{document}

\renewenvironment{Solution}[1]{\textbf{#1} }{\hspace{10pt}} %NEW

\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1] \section{Problems}

\begin{ex} 
\begin{questions} 
\question One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is not the same. Which one is different?

\begin{oneparchoices} 
\choice John 
\choice Paul 
\choice George 
\choice Ringo 
\choice Socrates \end{oneparchoices}
\begin{sol} 
Socrates 
\end{sol} 
\end{questions} \end{ex}

\begin{ex} \begin{questions} \stepcounter{question} \question One of these numbers is perfect.

\begin{oneparchoices} 
\choice $2$ 
\choice $28$ 
\choice $5$ 
\choice $3$ 
\choice $7$ \end{oneparchoices} \end{questions} 
\begin{sol} 
$7$ 
\end{sol} 
\end{ex}

\Closesolutionfile{ans} 
\section{Solutions} 
\input{ans1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much    you solved my problem @CrimsonRain